# Smartphone breaks the Internet connection when a call is received while wireless connection is on

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, android

I have this strange issue that I have *absolutely* no idea about with my HTC one X (Android 4.2.2) and Linksys Wireless-N ADSL2+ Modem Router WAG120N. Desktop has Windows 7 Ultimate running.

When I'm in the same room with the AP, I can connect to the internet via wireless connection on my HTC without any problem. However when I walk away, get outside the covered area when the wireless connection is on and turn back (like answering a call, talking in another room or simply forget the phone in my pocket, go get something from fridge and come back), the Internet connection is gone. Windows cannot troubleshoot the problem.

Well, after a fresh reset, I tried to trigger this issue deliberately. While the wireless connection was on, I got out and in the coverage area twice, nothing happened. I made a call for a few minutes, walking around, going outside the range and in. Finally when I get back to the PC, the connection was gone. ***Most of the time*, this happens when I receive a call when I am connected to LAN via wireless adapter.**

---

## **Symptoms**

**Chrome**: 192.168.1.1 : This webpage is not available

**ipconfig**

[image]

When I **troubleshoot** the connection the result is:

[image]

The only thing that I can do to restore the connection is to reset the router.

Does anyone else have this issue or heard of it? How do I fix this?

## Additional Info

I can almost confirm this has something to do with incoming calls. When this happens, if I'm connected to the network via wireless adapter, the above result occurs. Not only cannot I connect to the internet, also I cannot connect to my router via `192.168.1.1`. I tried today while I was on the Ethernet connection, broke the internet connection. Then I tried to connect with wireless and [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGrIr.png) were the results:

[image]

Comment: Look like you got your LAN properties manually configured....incorrectly...
Can you post a screenshot of LAN properties showing IP and gateway and DNS?

Comment: I use DNS as `4.2.2.1` and `4.2.2.2`, you an see my IP configuration above in the screenshots. This happens mostly when I receive a call while connected to network via wireless adapter.

Comment: Try to disable IPv6 for the local network on the router and [on the PC](http://www.informationweek.com/how-to-disable-ipv6-on-windows-7-/d/d-id/1099490). If no change, please give more information how you fix the problem once it happens ("fresh reset"?).

Comment: "fresh reset" = cut the power. wait 10 seconds. power the router up.

Comment: If I understand correctly, it's the router that needs to be restarted. If so, the problem is not with the PC. You could, after causing the problem, go into the router console (probably at http:192.168.1.1) and check its status and the log (if logging). This might help us to understand this better.

Comment: Default gateway is not available when the problem occurs. I enabled logging now and will trace the problem from now on. I'll let you know.

Comment: Have you disabled IPv6? You don't need it on a local network.

Answer (score 0):

I think from your description that your problem is your Win7 desktop machine loses connection with the WiFi AP whenever your HTC One X goes in and out of range, usually when its on a call?

When your HTC goes out of range and loses WiFi connectivity, the AP will initiate a rekey with all existing connected hosts to renegotiate the group key (otherwise the HTC will no longer be on the network, but will theoretically still be able to decrypt broadcast traffic - a security problem).

It's possible that your Windows machine is having problems handling this rekey exchange so gets kicked off the network by the AP. This is the only way I can think that the presence/absence of device on a wireless network can have an affect on an existing device.

To rule out this possibility, try using your WiFi with no encryption (i.e. open connection) and repeat the scenario, and report back what happens.

Comment: It is not only my win 7 machine, every device connected to network loses connection to the internet.

Comment: Let me clear this out: there are at least 3 devices connected to the network when this happens: win7 desktop, win8 laptop (well, this is sometimes, not always), and the HTC phone. Win7 is connected via Ethernet. When this happens, (1) all devices lose Internet connection. (2) No new devices can connect to network via wireless, it simply says 'cannot connect to network'. (3) only via Ethernet, one can join the network: that results in the same as win7 situation, illustrated above. In addition, no one can access the router via 192.168.1.1.